# Partition by column and map over that partition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL DataFrame and have a function which needs to be applied over all rows where `partition_col` are the same.

So far I know I can convert the DataFrame to an RDD and apply `mapPartitions` there. The issue I'm having is reliably ensuring that all instances which match the condition are in the same partition when the `mapPartitions` is run.

I have tried `df.repartition(partition_col).rdd.mapPartitions(...)` but that leaves me with some empty partitions so I'm not convinced it is doing what I want.

Comment: "df.repartition(partition_col)" is correct way, many empty partitions are not affects you. Please look section "repartition by column"  here: 

https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4

Comment: How about the window function? `w = Window.partitionBy(col("partition_col))` and then you do `df.withColumn("newColumnName", someFunction.over(w))` would that work? This will apply `someFunction` to rows partitioned by your selected column.

Comment: @astro_asz I need to apply the function over the rows together, and I guess doing it like that will apply it row wise. thanks though

Comment: Can you give example of a function you want to apply?

Comment: It is something like I need to sort the rows in the partition, split them into smaller groups based on their order, then take the first x rows of each of the smaller groups